# mvc3 routing not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have default routes from mvc3 like

```
{root}/account/details/123
```

and I want -

```
{root}/a/123
```

I tried this -

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Accounts_details", // Route name
        "a/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "account", action = "details", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

But it still gives me 404. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the action definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where this route is located? Is it's after the default route try to write it before default route.

Comment: Thanks, i had this route definition AFTER the default.